# How to make Golden Ratio Proportion Torus?

Tags: modeling, proportional-editing

I need to model this Torus. Can anyone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Andres, welcome to BSE. Can you please edit your question to  clarify what you mean by a 'Golden Ratio Torus' ? What dimensions of the torus are at this ratio to one another?  Must the torus be a wound spiral, as illustrated?

Comment: Hi Robin! The golden ratio si a proporcional meaning. I need to model a 3,5cm radius torus with two directions of spirals. One clockwise direction and the other no as seen on the imagen. The spirals have diferente depths. 7mm ANd 2mm